# Custom UITableViewCell to draw or not?

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I'm designing whole UI using storyboard and all is well but for table view cells it seems to be too much. Get's crowded in designer and views can vary good deal which calls for many outlets.

I decided to custom draw them. I understand process of doing it but 2 things bother me:

1. Performance. Will custom-drawn cells be slower than storyboarded ones?
2. Reuse. I understand how reuse works and it seems that completely "erasing" contents and re-drawing might be slower than just creating new cell every time. Is that true?

If you look at design - to me it seems to be easer to write and maintain complete drawing through the code because of font backgrounds, colors, lines, etc.

[image]

Comment: How many cells are we talking about?

Comment: No more than 50 in biggest list. Smaller lists usually just couple items

Comment: As long as I know, if you go the storyboard route, you still have a  separate prototype cell xib right? If so, what do you mean by custom drawn? Do you mean to dynamically create `UITextView`s etc.?

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. All the cells you show are the same except for the color, so that's just one prototype cell, which can be modified in tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:. You could create multiple cell types if you prefer (via copy an paste, then change the colors) if there aren't too many different ones.

Comment: I'm not sure how to create thin hairline with color using storyboard. Thats one example. Colored circle is another example, there is no such control. Vertical bars between text..